# Parse JSON from Server with Map Data

Tags: android, json, kotlin

I'm currently building apps using **Retrofit** and **Kotlin**. So far, I can parse JSON from office server. But, now I have a problem in mapping data. I already read about Kotlin map, but can't fully understand it. For my JSON from server, I can't upload it because there's a privacy to my company's data. So, I will use dummy JSON, but the structure same as my company's JSON. Here it is:

```
{"market":
   "101":
      {"name": "xxx",
       "image": "/folderPath/imageName.jpg"
      }
   "102":
      {"name": "yyy",
       "image": "/folderPath/image2Name.jpg"
      }
}
```

About the data class, I use List<> to initialize the data class, here it is:

```
data class Product(
  @SerializedName("Market") val Market: List<MarketContent> = listOf()
)

data class MarketContent(
  @SerializedName("Name") val Name: String,
  @SerializedName("Image") val Image: String
)
```

What I've tried in my RecyclerView adapter is like this:

```
class OtherProductAdapter(private val otherProductList: List<MarketContent>, private val clickListener: (MarketContent) -> Unit) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.other_product, parent, false)
    return ListOther(v)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    (holder as ListOther).bindItem(otherProductList[position], clickListener)
}

override fun getItemCount() = otherProductList.size

class ListOther(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){

    private val rImg = itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.rv_image)

    fun bindItem(t: MarketContent, clickListener: (MarketContent) -> Unit){
        itemView.rv_title.text = t.Name
        Glide.with(itemView.context).load("http://192.168.1.100:3232" +t.Image).into(rImg)
        itemView.setOnClickListener {clickListener(t)}
    }
}
}
```

And here, is my retrofit

```
private fun getInto() {
    val apiService = ProductApiService()
    disposable =
            apiService.syncData()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(
                    { result -> intoData(result) },
                    { error -> Log.e("Error", error.message) }
                )
}

private fun intoData(result: Product) {
    rv_view?.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
    rv_view?.hasFixedSize()
    rv_view?.adapter = OtherProductAdapter(result.Market, { item: MarketContent -> clickedItem(item) })
}
```

As the result, my app is not showing any data and there's a message:

> E/Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 109719 path $.Market

Help me how should I map the JSON data. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The issue is that the JSON you're receiving is a JSON object (not an array), but you're trying to deserialise it to a `List<MarketContent>`

Comment: you json is invalid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need to change mapping like

```
@SerializedName("Market") val Market: Map<String, MarketContent> = mapOf()
```

Comment: sorry for late reply, then, how should I call it in adapter?

Comment: You can just use map values. In OtherProductAdapter just pass Market.values()